# Delphi - creating a program which docks to side of monitor

Tags: windows, delphi, dock

using Delphi 2010, how can I create my program to be dockable?  For example, certain program can be docked to the top of the Windows desktop.  Think Dragon Naturally Speaking, which always has a control bar at the top of the monitor.  If I open up another app, such as MS-Word, and maximize it, it maximizes to all the space -except- the space used by the Dragon toolbar.  The windows taskbar has a similar behaviour.  It is always in a certain place, it is not resizable, and when another app is being run and maximized, the taskbar is NOT hidden.

What is the easiest way to write a program, in Delphi, which locks itself to the top of the monitor (maybe 150 pixels "tall"), and nothing can be put over top of it, even when other programs are maximized?

Thanks

Comment: It seems which you are looking for an [Application Desktop Toolbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776821%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Try the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553088/reserve-part-of-the-desktop)

Comment: There's a Delphi wrapper for AppBars [here](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=93) - see TAppBar. It's old, but can be updated and reworked for more recent versions of Delphi (and Windows), and it's much better than starting from scratch to implement your own. There's some limited docs with it that explain how to use it, as well as a fairly complete (although a little buggy in spots) demo app.

Comment: FWIW every time I have encountered a program that included an app bar, the very next thing I did was uninstall the software. By and large users loath app bars because they consume valuable screen real estate. It has to be a special program indeed to warrant an app bar. Shell taskbar is fine. It is so fundamental to the operation of the machine. Are you sure you program is going to be important enough to the user to warrant an app bar?

Comment: <David> The program is for a gym which uses personal trainers.  There are people walking in all the time who have to be checked in.  This is the main functionality of the computer. Using Word, etc, while needed, is secondary...  It could be written ala "gadget" syle for Windows 7, aka small window, but then you have to make sure it is always on top, etc...

Comment: Note that when an application goes full screen (not to be confused with maximized), a desktop toolbar is supposed to give way to it (like the task bar).

Comment: @KenWhite That link further references a dead link... at GEOCITIES of all things. Didn't Geocities die off a long time ago? Anyway, there's an updated version here: https://github.com/kami-soft/ApplicationDesktopToolbar

Comment: @JerryDodge: The link in my comment was put there just short of a decade ago. It may possibly be outdated, don't you think? And you thought it was necessary to bring it to my attention after almost 10 years because....? It's in a comment, not an answer. Are you calling out everyone on SO who left a link in a comment years ago that has since expired?

Comment: @Ken No, just happened to see your comment right after finding that same link during my research. Thought I'd tip you for future reference, and I found it odd that Geocities would have still been around in 2014. Meaning, back at that time of your comment, it was likely already a dead link.

Comment: @JerryDodge: Again, after a decade, it's unlikely that I would even remember that comment (I didn't), much less care about it. At the time I posted the link, I would have made sure that it was valid at that point. Haven't tracked it or verified the accuracy of any links it contained to see if they remained valid.